# Is there a difference in adding RWD for plain JS vs AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, responsive-design, difference

It might by silly question, but i haven't got any experience in neither Responsive Web Design nor AngularJS, cause I am still learning plain JS.
I wonder if there is any or at least minimum difference in HTML and CSS, when i got application made in plain JS and the same application in AngularJS (one application in two "versions").
I am asking, because i would like to know if i have to make also two "versions" of RWD (for plain JS app and AngularJS) or it can be just one RWD, because HTML and CSS code won't change, so RWD will work on both?
Briefly - is there a difference for a RWD if an app is made in plain JS or AngularJS - is RWD independent from JS code (no matter what framework is used, if any is)?

Comment: This question is really too broad for a definitive answer.  However, You can safely assume that even though a site designed using RWD principles may not depend on a framework, or a framework depend on RWD, there will probably be customizations needed for RWD elements to function efficiently with framework features.

Comment: It's simple question :) If i have an app made in plain JS and in Angular JS, then should i made RWD separately for plain JS and for AngularJS or will one RWD be enough for both plain JS and AngularJS? If an app will have same HTML structure and CSS styles, but only JS code changes (plain vs framework), then one RWD implementation should be enough, i think.

Comment: it really isn't that simple.  RWD isn't a software, or service, or platform, it is a *design approach*.  How you decide to **implement** the concepts of RWD will be highly affected by which framework features you are using. certain CSS classes may need to be redesigned to support dynamic object repetition, for example, or effects catered explicitly to content transitions without page reloads (common in most SPA frameworks).

Answer (score 1):

> Is RWD independent from JS code (no matter what framework is used, if
>   any is)?

Largely, yes. As a concept, RWD is not framework dependent and is CSS and HTML dependent. If a framework utilizes some sort of canned CSS and/or HTML, it is possible that it would favor (or not favor) responsive design.
Key concepts in RWD are almost entirely CSS related.

If you consider progressive enhancement part of RWD then framework choice is important.

Comment: So one implementation of RWD should work both with plain JS and AngularJS (or other framework)? I know that AngularJS changes (or interferes) HTML code, adding bindings to it. But that shouldn't be a problem for RWD implementation?

Comment: If you're careful, you should be able to use the same classes and therefore mostly the same CSS. Angular's bindings aren't relevant to responsiveness.